# Segmentation fault when trying to fill a vector as instance variable

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, segmentation-fault, adjacency-matrix

I want to make a filled matrix as an instance variable in my .hpp file but end up with seg fault.

I have a graphe class.
In my .cpp file, i filled an adjacency matrix as follows

```
void Graphe::shortRoute( void ){
    std::vector<vector<int>> matrix(_adjacences.size(), vector<int>(_adjacences.size()));
    std::vector<vector<int>> shortPath(_adjacences.size(), vector<int>(_adjacences.size()));
    
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++) {
                for (auto j : *_adjacences[i]) {
                        matrix[i][j->sommetArrive] = j->longueur;
                }
        } 
... more and more code to get a filled shortPath matrix.
```

I implemented Floyd algorithm and everything works perfectly here
and I printed the matrix to check it, it's all good.

the resulted matrices `matrix` and `shortPath` I wanted to make as instance variables

I tried as follows **THIS CAUSES SEG FAULT WHY ?**

```
for ( unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++)
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < _adjacences.size(); j++){
         shortPath[i][j] = SP[i][j];
         matrix[i][j] = M[i][j];
    }
```

and in my .hpp file I declared SP and M as follows:

```
class Graphe
{
private:
    vector< vector< Arc * > * > _adjacences;
    std::vector<vector<int>> M;
    std::vector<vector<int>> SP;
....
```

as soon as I launch the program, i get seg fault from that new addition

Arc is as follows:

```
class Arc
{
public:
    int sommetArrive;
    int longueur;
    string nom;

    Arc( int a_sommetArrive, int a_longueur, string a_nom );
    virtual ~Arc( void );

    friend ostream & operator <<( ostream &, Arc const & );
};
```

Comment: As soon as you introduced pointers, we need to see where, how, and when those pointers become initialized.

Comment: When you asked this a few hours ago, we asked you to present a [mcve] so that we can actually help you. That still applies, even though you deleted the original question. Cheers

Comment: I didn't get what minimal example means, I can't make an example because my program reads values from an XML file and point to them that's why :(

Comment: I have 2 matrices filled with int, how can i make them as instance variables in my Graphe class ? that's my question

Comment: @KingAzaiez -- Read your own question and look at what you've provided to us.  Do you think it's possible to give you an answer, except to tell you "your program has one or more bugs"?

Comment: We keep giving you a link that explains what to do...

Comment: alright I'll try to make an example, i'll minimize my program sir

Comment: Also, why should it matter where the data comes from?  You should be testing your class against a simple 3x3 or 4x4 matrix first.  If your testing this with some huge matrix, and you aren't even sure if the simplest data works, that doesn't make a lot of sense, wouldn't you say?

Comment: yeah I get your point, I'll make an example right away

Comment: @KingAzaiez Not what you are asking about but this code `for ( unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++) for (unsigned j = 0; j < _adjacences.size(); j++){ shortPath[i][j] = SP[i][j]; matrix[i][j] = M[i][j]; }` can be simplified to this `shortPath = SP; matrix = M;` You don't have to write loops to copy vectors, the whole vector can be copied in a single assignment. I have a suspicion this might even cure your problem.

Comment: @john thanks again bro, it worked, and I can't thank you enough :'D, can you post it as an answer so i can accept it ?

Comment: @KingAzaiez OK done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not what you are asking about but this code

```
for ( unsigned i = 0; i < _adjacences.size(); i++) 
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < _adjacences.size(); j++) { 
        shortPath[i][j] = SP[i][j]; 
        matrix[i][j] = M[i][j]; 
    }
```

can be simplified to this

```
 shortPath = SP; 
 matrix = M;
```

You don't have to write loops to copy vectors, the whole vector can be copied in a single assignment.

I have a suspicion this might even cure your problem. If so then the original problem was probably that the `shortPath` and `matrix` vectors are zero size, so the loop code is assigning to vector elements that don't exist. When you copy a vector using a single assignment the size of the vector you are copying to changes to match the size of the vector you are copying from.